# invalidating a picture control of an openGL in MFC Dialog

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

I have MFC dialog containing a picture control.
the picture control displays openGL.
I update the whole dialog in `OnMouseMove();` using `invalidate(FALSE);`
this way it works, but with glithes on all the buttons on the dialog.
when I invalidate only the picture control containing the openGL, I can not see any update.

```
m_PicCtrl.Invalidate(FALSE);
```

I also tried

```
m_PicCtrl.RedrawWindow(NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE);
```

with different flags, but now way!!
how can I invalidate (update) only the picture control to avoid the glithes that appear if I invalidate all the dialog ?

Comment: Have you tried `InvalidateRect(NULL, FALSE)` on the OpenGL control? It's been a long time since I (sort of) understood these Win32 details, but it might be worth a quick try anyway.

Comment: It doesn't work with both: InvalidateRect(NULL, FALSE) and InvalidateRect(NULL, TRUE)